# Cannot run Ruby script as a cronjob

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron, environment

I'm struggling with running a Ruby script as a cronjob. I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 as root, have RVM as the Ruby manager installed and the following in my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc

*/15 * * * * /usr/local/rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby /root/scripts/script.rb
```

I'm using an absolute path to ensure that it is definitely working. I know that cron is not loading the same environment, and I pressume it has something to do with that, but I cannot fiddle it out.

Comment: use whenever gem to make your life easier.

Comment: What error/behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @MicahElliott When I'm checking logs, I can see that the job was running, but the script does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

See "[Using RVM with Cron](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron)".

The environment has to be set up also because typical cronjobs are run by root which has limited environmental information; Things like PATH are much more restricted. It's not sufficient to only call Ruby via RVM's shim.

You can force the job to run as you, which would pick up your environment but then would run with your permissions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. According to your link I tried to call the wrapper directly, but I got `require': cannot load such file -- curb (LoadError)` (curb is the first gem I require in the script, I guess this applies to other gems as well)